# Speed up macro for large files (over 90000 rows, 236 columns)

Tags: vba, performance, excel

I wrote a macro that compares the columns B, which contains file numbers, in two worksheets. There are three possibilities: the file number exists in both columns, the file number exists only in the first column and the file number exists only in the second column. If e.g. the file number exists in both columns, the macro should copy/paste the entire row to another sheet. Same for the other two scenario's.

My code work perfect for a small file (around 500 rows, 236 columns), but for the large files it doesn't work. It takes way too long, and at the end it just crashes. I already tried the usual tricks to speed up the macro.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPasteWorksheets()

Dim wbDec As Workbook, wbJune As Workbook, wbAnalysis As Workbook
Dim wsDec As Worksheet, wsJune As Worksheet
Dim PresPres As Worksheet, PresAbs As Worksheet, AbsPres As Worksheet

'Stop screen from updating to speed things up
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Add 3 new worksheets. They each represent a different category, namely the one with already existing insurances, one with new insurances
'and one with the insurances that are closed due to mortality, lapse or maturity. Add two (temporary) worksheets to paste the databases.

Worksheets.Add().Name = "PresPres"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "PresAbs"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "AbsPres"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "DataDec"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "DataJune"

'Define the active workbook

Set wbAnalysis = ThisWorkbook

'Define the first database. Copy/paste the sheet and close them afterwards.

Set wbDec = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="F:\Risk_Management_2\Embedded_Value\2015\20151231\Data\DLL\Master Scala\Extract.xlsx")

wbDec.Sheets("SCALA").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
wbAnalysis.Sheets("DataDec").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wbDec.Close

'We have to do the same for the other database. We cannot do it at the same time, because both files have the same name,
'and can't be opened at the same time.

Set wbJune = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="F:\Risk_Management_2\Embedded_Value\2016\20160630\Data\DLL\Master Scala\extract.xlsx")

wbJune.Sheets("SCALA").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
wbAnalysis.Sheets("DataJune").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wbJune.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Sub Compare()

Dim DataDec As Worksheet, DataJune As Worksheet
Dim lastRowDec As Long
Dim lastRowJune As Long
Dim lastRowPresAbs As Long
Dim lastRowPresPres As Long
Dim lastRowAbsPres As Long
Dim foundTrue As Boolean
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long

'Define the last row of the different sheets
lastRowDec = Sheets("DataDec").Cells(Sheets("DataDec").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowJune = Sheets("DataJune").Cells(Sheets  ("DataJune").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowPresAbs = Sheets("PresAbs").Cells(Sheets("PresAbs").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowPresPres = Sheets("PresPres").Cells(Sheets ("PresPres").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowAbsPres = Sheets("AbsPres").Cells(Sheets("AbsPres").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'Compare the file numbers in column B of both sheets. If they are the same, copy/paste the entire row to sheet PresPres,
'if they are not, copy/paste the entire row to sheet PresAbs.

For i = 1 To lastRowDec
foundTrue = False
For j = 1 To lastRowJune

If Sheets("DataDec").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("DataJune").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
    foundTrue = True
    Sheets("PresPres").Rows(lastRowPresPres + 1) = Sheets("DataDec").Rows(i)
    lastRowPresPres = lastRowPresPres + 1
    Exit For
End If

Next j

If Not foundTrue Then
Sheets("DataDec").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
Sheets("PresAbs").Rows(lastRowPresAbs + 1)
lastRowPresAbs = lastRowPresAbs + 1

End If

Next i


'Look if there are file numbers that are only present in June's database. If so, copy/paste entire row to sheet AbsPres.
For k = 1 To lastRowJune
foundTrue = False
For l = 1 To lastRowDec

If Sheets("DataJune").Cells(k, 1).Value = Sheets("DataDec").Cells(l,     1).Value Then
    foundTrue = True
    Exit For
End If

Next l

If Not foundTrue Then
Sheets("DataJune").Rows(k).Copy Destination:= _
Sheets("AbsPres").Rows(lastRowAbsPres + 1)
lastRowAbsPres = lastRowAbsPres + 1

End If

Next k

'Stop screen from updating to speed things up.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I've added some comments to explain what I'm trying to do. I'm relatively new to VBA so I believe I'm not coding very efficient.

Could someone have a look and try to make it work?

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to achieve, have a look at [VLookUp](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). You should be able to use this either directly in your Excel file or in your VBA code

Answer (score 2):

Basically what your are doing is comparing 2 column of elements, you want to know when:

1. an element is in both columns
2. an element is only in the first column
3. an element is only in the second column

To do that, **your solution** do:

1. For each element in column 1,
2. Find if there is this element in column 2
3. If found, it is in both, if not, it's just in 1
4. Continue to next element in column 1
5. Do quite the same with the element of the column 2

So basically, your examining column 2 for each element of column 1
And the same for the column 1 with the element of column 2

if we consider n the length of column1 and m the length of column2.
That is roughly 2*m*n comparison.
That's a lot !

**My solution**:
You are looking for numbers in column B.
Therefore you can sorted both sheet base on the value in column B

Then you can:

1. Create counter1 and counter2 referring to the current row in sheet1 and sheet2
2. Compare the value of sheet1.Value('B' + counter1) to sheet2.Value('B' + counter2)
3. Then you have 3 choice :
   a) That is the same value, then copy the line in the right file and increments both counter
   b) Value from sheet1 is greater, then you will never find the value from sheet2 in sheet1. So copy the line of sheet2 in the right file and increment only the counter2
   c) The opposite
4. Do that until counter1 or counter2 is at the end.
5. As it is possible that both won't be at the end at the same time, you will have to copy the remaining lines in the right file as they will never be in the "finished" sheet.

With that solution, you will only read each "column" once ! So roughly about m+n comparison :)
You win a lot of time :)

With M=n=90 000:

- you have a solution with about m*n=8 100 000 000 comparison
- the other solution is just about 180 000 comparison

Answer (score 0):

This should be the fastest approach as copying all data at once is much faster than copying it by row.

Select both columns > Home tab > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Duplicate Values...

Now you need a filter from `Data` > `Filter`, but for that you will need to insert a header row above the numbers. After you have the filter, you can click on the second column filter and Filter by Color. Now you can copy the visible cells to wherever you copy the duplicates. I recommend sorting by color too before copying as copying one contiguous area should be a bit faster.

You can use the same method for the other two cases by filtering the columns with Filter by Color > No Fill.

Before you Record Macro of the process you can select View tab > Macros > Use Relative References.

**Edit**

I think I misunderstood the question. This method needs both columns to be next to each other, so if they are in separate sheets you can copy and insert them in column A. You can hide the column after the filter is applied. Then you can delete the column and header rows if needed.

Similar approach without conditional formatting is to inset a column with a helper function that checks if the id exists in the other sheet, but I think it will be a bit slower. For example:

```
= CountIf( Sheet2!A1:A1234, B2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer to my question on the Mr. Excel forum:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/963415-visual-basic-applications-speed-up-macro-large-file.html

Thanks for your answers!